# Relative and Absolute Position CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

Trying to make 'tab2' move with the nav bar. (when you hover the nav the box moves out with it)
http://jsfiddle.net/Bz5mn/
Help!

```
   #nav
{
min-width: 60px;
width:5%;
height:100%;
background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transition-duration:0.4s;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [adjacent sibling selector](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors/combinators/adjacent_sibling). You can do something like

```
#nav:hover + #tab2 {
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

You'd also want to add your transition to the `#tab2` declaration so that the animation matches.

Also note that this selector [only works in IE 9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

[Here's a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz5mn/5/)

Comment: @applewood If you are happy with this answer, up vote it so that we all know that this issue is over and done with.  You also gain reputation points for accepting answers, which will increase your credibility in SO and encourage others to help you in the future.